# Why can't we initialize state arrays/hashes in list context?

Tags: perl, initialization

There is a restriction on arrays and hashes as state variables. We can't initialize them in list context as of Perl 5.10:

So

```
state @array = qw(a b c); #Error!
```

Why is it so? Why this is not allowed?

We can use state arrays and initialize them by this way

```
state @numbers;
push @numbers, 5;
push @numbers, 6;
```

but why not directly do it by `state @numbers = qw(5 6);`

Why doesn't Perl allow it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [perldiag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html#Initialization-of-state-variables-in-list-context-currently-forbidden), support for list context initialization is planned for a future release:

> - Initialization of state variables in list context currently forbidden
>     (F) Currently the implementation of "state" only permits the initialization of scalar variables in scalar context. Re-write `state ($a) = 42` as `state $a = 42` to change from list to scalar context. Constructions such as `state (@a) = foo()` will be supported in a future perl release.

According to [this message about the change that made this an error](http://www.mail-archive.com/perl5-changes@perl.org/msg18436.html):

> For now, forbid all list assignment initialisation of state variables,
>   as the precise semantics in Perl 6 are not clear. Better to make it a
>   syntax error, than to have one behaviour now, but change it later.
>   [I believe that this is the consensus. If not, it will be backed out]

You could always use an arrayref instead:

```
state $arrayRef = [qw(a b c)];
```

Note that your example of

```
state @numbers;
push @numbers, 5;
push @numbers, 6;
```

does **not** mean the same thing that `state @numbers = qw(5 6)` would (if it worked).  A `state` variable is only initialized once, but your code would push 5 & 6 onto the array every time that code was executed.

Answer (score 8):

Horrible workaround:

```
state @array;
state $array_is_initialized;
unless ($array_is_initialized) {
    $array_is_initialized = 1;
    @array = (1,2,3);
}
```

Comment: I think just using a closure instead of `state` will be easier.

Comment: Also, `@array` evaluates to false if `@array` is not initialized, so this could be: `state @array; if (!@array) { @array = 1, 2, 3; }`

Comment: @AFresh1: not if empty is one of the possible initialized values

Answer (score 5):

It simply hasn't been written, because it's kind of hard, and getting it to work for scalars was considered to be more important. There's an opcheck (`Perl_ck_sassign` in `op.c`) that recognizes when the left side of an assignment is a `padsv` op referring to a newly-declared `state` variable and wraps it in a special `once` op that makes sure that the assignment only happens once -- but it doesn't even attempt to recognize list assignments, probably due to the difficulty of breaking up a `(state $a, my $b, state $c) = (1, 2, 3)` type construct. Funny though, it seems like `state @a = qw(blah blah blah)` would be easy enough, and clearly it's a less pathological case than the other list assignment variant.

Answer (score 2):

Another work around:

```
{
    my @array = qw(1 2 3);
    sub foo {
        print join(", ", @array);
    }
}

foo();
```

Provides a similar result as using state (in this case, scopes it to a function without destroying it when leaving the function). Uses the fact that function declarations are global in Perl.

[Source](http://perlmaven.com/static-and-state-variables-in-perl)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a good answer to your question. I can't say for sure, but my guess is that perl just never supported the one-time initialization that would be implied by your first code (I assume that is what you wanted).

You could do:

```
state @array;
@array = qw( a b c );
```

Doing this would simply be the same as using a "my" variable rather than a "state" one.

Comment: I asked about the state arrays/hashes not my :-/

Comment: @Ron that has a different effect though. `state $x = 42` only sets `$x` to 42 *once*; `state $x; $x = 42` sets `$x` to 42 every time it's run. `state @array = qw(a b c)` simply doesn't work at all, but `state @array; @array = qw(a b c)` resets the value of `@array` every time it's run.